# Can I split the setup.sql in several scripts? If so how should I do it?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

My team and I are developing an application using Snowflake's new Native App Framework. We would like to be able to divide the `setup.sql` into several scripts since it is becoming too big to maintain.

Ideally, we would have a directory named "`setup_scripts`" which contains several other scripts to setup the structures for each feature, i.e. "`setup_scripts/feature1.sql`", "`setup_scripts/feature2.sql`" ... From the "`setup.sql`" we would have several calls to the scripts inside "`setup_scripts`".

Is it possible to achieve such a result or something similar? If so how is it achieved?

Comment: if they are sql/proc etc, you can call them using snowflake Tasks https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tasks-intro